# How to call a function in build time through webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have a function which will perform some performance heavy task. The function will store the result in a global variable and in next call, when the result will already exists, I will do other cheap operation.[check this link](https://codesandbox.io/s/j4ply3mx39?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js)

At this point I want to call this function *once* while building and storing the result in a global variable, so all calls are cheap due to caching.

```
reduceFn({
    param1:"good",
    param2:"something"
});

let globalVariable = [];

function reduceFn({param1, param2}) {
    if (param1 in globalVariable) {
        //cheap operation
    } else {
        // some performace heavy task and
        globalVariable.push(param1);
    }
}
```

Comment: hmmm, I dont really get why do you need to do that. maybe you can use memoize to calculate that value instead of fixing in building stage.

Comment: I am creating a function which create a reducer if not available and replace all reducers and then calling action, but this is very performance heavy. So I want to create all reducers in build time so that next call will just call action. check this link https://codesandbox.io/s/j4ply3mx39?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js

Answer (score 1):

You can use DefinePlugin which is a webpack plugin to create a global variable which will be accessible from your code:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({ YOUR_GLOBAL_VARAIBLE_NAME: yourFunction() })
```